# Initialise a Vector of object in Java, always not right

Tags: java, vector, initialization

```
Vector<Pair> Pairs = new Vector<Pair>();
for (int i=0; i!= Size; i++){
        Pair p = new Pair();
        Pairs.add(p);
        System.out.println(i+ " "+ Pairs.get(i).Pair); // first output
    }

     for(int i=0; i!=Pairs.size();i++){
            System.out.println("p"+ i+ " "+ Pairs.get(i).Pair); // second output

    }
```

I initialise a vector of Pair class, and the Pair class will generate two double numbers randomly, then I try to create a vector of pairs as above code, the two outputs are produced when the vector is in initialisation, one is after the vector Pairs is made. why the results are different, and the second part of output just repeat the same element, but they are supposed to be the same.
The output are:

```
0 [-0.9771848260519362, 0.3677255241044455]
1 [-0.453064196696608, 0.10266228385031217]
2 [0.7337531470828571, -0.9331922628126463]
3 [-0.8083142272953654, -0.8923373383889719]
4 [0.19338350002773197, 0.8060945513704245]
5 [0.01753932066182662, 0.4739045577520977]
6 [-0.10060179118660373, 0.5392480353575093]
7 [0.01970274932747107, 0.4450926528405188]
8 [-0.7520808447905654, -0.4791789391059751]
9 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p0 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p1 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p2 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p3 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p4 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p5 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p6 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p7 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p8 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
p9 [0.4907563252803737, 0.7654845250011753]
```

Comment: show us the `Pair` class, I suspect that the error's in there.

Comment: Why are you using the legacy `Vector` type instead of a `List`?

Comment: Please respect the Java naming conventions. Don't use public fields: it's bad practice. And don't use Vector, it's obsolete for more than 10 years. Use an ArrayList.

Comment: Unless you do something really strange in the `toSTring` method of your `Pair` class you do not share with us your exact test. You will not get such an output.

Comment: Please don't tell me that you have static variables in your Pair class, to represent the values in Pair.

Comment: By the way the code looks, it's like you have a static `Pair` object in your `Pair` class.

Comment: Yes, I do have static variables, so whats wrong here ? I am confused in this point. Could you please tell me about this ?

Comment: `static` makes the variable global, so any adjustment to the value of that variable adjusts the value for all instances of the class which contains the variable.

Comment: @JBNizet `Vector` keeps popping up with beginners. I speculate there's a whole bunch of being learning Java from outdated books that use `Vector.

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop shows the pair that was last created in the first loop. You probably made the Pair field static, which means that all the Pair instances share a unique version. A static field belongs to the class it's defined in. A non-static field belongs to the instance of the class.

Read the [Java tutorial about this topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).